# Animating DataGrid rows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, datagrid, expression-blend

I would like to add an animation to a `DataGrid`, which is applied to every row when they are loaded.

Like the following:

[image: Blur animation.]

For example in that one, each row is blurred out and gets focus.

I tried editing the `GridRowStyle` template of my `DataGrid` and adding an even trigger for `OnLoaded` even to fire the animation. It works, but as it is fast, all the rows get updated almost at the same time so the animation fires on all of them.

How can I introduce a delay on the rows, so the last row will fire the even later than the first?

Comment: Are you specifically needing a `DataGrid` or could you use a custom `ItemsControl` with effects applied to your `ItemsPanel` and `ItemsTemplate` instead?

Comment: I don't specifically need a `DataGrid`, but I will have to load a lot of items into it, so I'm afraid that there would be performance issues with using something other than `DataGrid`.

Comment: That's what a `VirtualizingStackPanel` is for as the `ItemsPanel` :D but it's just an option for adding an effect to individual items like you're thinking towards

Comment: I'll check it out. Any ideas how to approach it?

Comment: Ya basically if it were me I would attach an OnLoad event to the ItemTemplate with a buffertime at the end so it would do your focus in, wait a second, then the next item would do the same. Make sense? Would take some tinkering but should be do-able.